# SQL Server 2019 Master Data Services Filtering on Numeric

Tags: knockout.js, master-data-services, sql-server-2019

I have recently upgraded a MDS 2017 instance to 2019.  After the update, users are experiencing an error when trying to filter on a Number Type Attribute within an Entity view on the web interface.  I can find no reported instances of this online.  Microsoft is using knockout js, and I am wondering if perhap there is a way to bypass this particular issue.

More details:
  When a user select Filter from the Entity view, then selects an attribute to filter on that is a Number data type, the Criteria box is immediately ringed in red and a message displayed "The number is not valid."  While the user can type in this Criteria box, nothing will change the validation error, and the "Apply" button remains greyed out.   This happens with ALL numeric attributes in the system, except the built in Code field.  Have tried changing the entry mask, (which there are only 2 options), and tried actually editing 'koFilterView.js' to try to bypass by always returning valid during the number check.  The later option allows the "Apply" button to function, but no results are returned, and the box still highlights red with the "not valid" message.
  I did submit as bug to MS but have had zero response and this is a mission critical application, so filtering on numeric values like composite date keys is an issue.

Looking for any suggestions on how to work around.

Answer (score 2):

We also experienced this issue after upgrading to MDS 2019.  Fortunately, we are still in the testing phase when we found it.

What has worked for us is to edit the file you mention. After editing the js file, all clients will need to clear cached files from their browser.

> ...\Master Data Services\Web
>   Application\Scripts\UserControls\KoFilterView.js

Look for the following line in KoFilterView.js:

```
if (isInteger(value - 0)) {
```

and replace with:

```
if (Number.isInteger(value - 0)) {
```

Hope this helps!